# How do I output an error message for a non-numeric input?

Tags: java

new programmer here.

Just a quick question - as mentioned already in the Title:

How do I output an error message for a non-numeric input ?

Example, person enters a letter for an int classified input - the compiler produces an error of: "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

How do I actually make it output an error message within the program itself?

Cause I'm wanting the program to keep looping to request an input again til a specified requirement has been met to exit the program.

Comment: please post your code, so that you get better suggestion on how this can be done on top of what logic you have already written.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related to your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16861633/1065197

Comment: Java Exception Handling: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put your parsing in a `try-catch` statement:

```
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(yourString);

} catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    System.out.println("Not a valid number!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The message that you described is resulted from an **Exception** [(tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) that was not handled by your program.

You can handle such an exception using the try-catch construct.

```
try
{
    // Getting a number from input
}
catch(InputMismatchException ex)
{
    // do something to recover.
}
```

As a side note - the exception is thrown by the Java runtime, and not by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and parse the input as a number and catch a `NumberFormatException`. Consider using `Integer.valueOf(String)`. This will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the input is not a valid integer. You can `catch` this exception using a [try-catch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) block.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the input by using the `isNumeric` method from the `NumericUtils` class. The class is from the `org.apache.commons.lang.math` package.

You can have a look at the [java docs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber%28java.lang.String%29)

If this method returns `false` then display the corresponding error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it programmatically. Put your suspected code under try catch block and in case exception print/or throw required error message. For example if you want to print error message if user enters number less than 10

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
int numberEntered=user_input.nextInt();
while(numberEntered<=10)
{
System.out.println("Please enter number greater than 10");
}
```