# How do you check for invalid user input?

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, user-input

I was writing a program to check for a user's age and then give them feedback upon their response. However, I cannot find out how to prompt the user with an error message of sorts in the event that the input they enter is not an integer. How can I work around this?

```java
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ifStatements {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (1 == 1) {
            int age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Age: "));

            if (age >= 75) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are old!");
                break;
            } else if (age >= 18) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an adult!");
                break;
            } else if (age > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are not an adult!");
                break;
            } else if (age <= 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid response!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the error messages when the user inputs any value that is not an integer. In this specific case I typed "w". I would like to be able to detect all data types. May be overkill, but I want to learn how to handle all exceptions even in the case of something as mediocre as this small program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "w"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:781)
    at ifStatements.main(ifStatements.java:16)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I output an error message for a non-numeric input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278183/how-do-i-output-an-error-message-for-a-non-numeric-input)

Comment: The code threw a `NumberFormatException`.  You might be interested in this [Exception Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html). Pay attention to the `try` / `catch` part.  Or, look for [other try / catch tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+try+catch+tutorial) .

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this.  Just re-prompt for bad input.  And Java conventions specify that class names should start with uppercase.

```
public class IfStatements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int age = 0;
        while (age <= 0) {
            try {
                age = Integer.parseInt(
                        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Age: "));
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                displayError();
                continue;
            }
            if (age >= 75) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are old!");
                break;
            } else if (age >= 18) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an adult!");
                break;
            } else if (age > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are not an adult!");
                break;
            }
            // must be <= 0 here so just display the message.
            displayError();
            
        }
    }
    private static void displayError() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "Please enter a number > 0", "Invalid Input",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The *[Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))* method will throw a *[NumberFormatException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)* if the string does not contain a parsable integer.

You can utilize a *[try-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)* block to capture the thrown exception.

The syntax is as follows.

```java
try {

} catch (ExceptionType name) {

}
```

When a statement within the *try*-block throws an exception, the block is exited and entered at the *catch*-block.

You can access the *Exception* object via the name declared at the start of the *catch*-block.

Here is an example of your code, utilizing a *try-catch* to validate the input value.

```java
int age;
while (1 == 1) {
    try {
        age = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Age: "));
        if (age >= 75) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are old!");
            break;
        } else if (age >= 18) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are an adult!");
            break;
        } else if (age > 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You are not an adult!");
            break;
        } else if (age <= 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid response!");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid age");
    }
}
```

Here is a basic demonstration, adapted from your code, which uses an *exception* to pass an invalid *age* input.

The *age* method will attempt to parse the value returned by *[JOptionPane#showInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object))*.
If it is successful it will return the value, otherwise, if an exception is thrown, it's caught and a new *[IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)* exception is thrown, with the input value as the *message*.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int age;
    boolean exit;
    do {
        exit = true;
        try {
            age = age();
            if (age >= 75) message("You are old!");
            else if (age >= 18) message("You are an adult!");
            else if (age > 0) message("You are not an adult!");
            else {
                message("Invalid response!");
                exit = false;
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException exception) {
            String string = exception.getMessage();
            if (string != null) {
                if (string.isBlank()) message("Input required");
                else message("Invalid age, '%s'".formatted(exception.getMessage()));
                exit = false;
            }
        }
    } while (!exit);
}

static int age() throws IllegalArgumentException {
    String string = null;
    try {
        string = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your Age: ");
        return Integer.parseInt(string);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(string);
    }
}

static void message(String string) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string);
}
```